# Java - add method conflicting with exception

Tags: java, exception

Ive been sitting with this for 2 hours now and I can't find a solution. I can't add more than one Friend to my ArrayList, because if the phone is null it casts the exception from my `getFriend()` method instead of adding it to the list. What is a simple way to work around this?

```
/**
 *  Ensures you can only add a friend if a friend with same phone number doesn't exist
 *  @param f as Friend
 *  @return boolean
 */

public boolean addFriend(Friend f){  
   if(getFriend(f.getPhone()) == null) {
       friends.add(f);
       return true;
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Member with that phone already exists");
       System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
       return false;
   }  
}


/**
 *  Searches the arraylist for a friend matching phone
 *  
 *  @param phone as String
 *  @return Friend if matching phone, else returns a null
 */
public Friend getFriend(String phone) {
    Friend res = null;
    if(friends.size() != 0){
        for(Friend f : friends) {
            if(f.getPhone().equals(phone)){
                res = f;
            }
        }
        if(res == null){
          throw new NullPointerException("No result found");
        }
   }
    return res;       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
if(res == null){
      throw new NullPointerException("No result found");
}
```

to simply return `null`.

As you are checking for `null` it will be safe.

```
public Friend getFriend(String phone) {
if(friends.size() != 0){
    for(Friend f : friends) {
        if(f.getPhone().equals(phone)){
            return f;
        }
    }
}
return null;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(res == null && friends.size() == 0){
```

How about that? Is that a valid solution?

Comment: Nope. Would recommend Scary Wombats solution that changes the whole 'architecture'. To get rid of the Exception.

Comment: U welcome. Btw the arraylist has the isEmpty() method to check for emptyness returning a boolean. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty--